# Sine predictions from ML.NET not really working

Tags: c#, .net, ml.net

I am currently experimenting with ML.NET but with the very first project I get stuck. I am trying to make a prediction of sine values.

1. Generating a list of X and Y values with a function for sine (y = sin(x))
2. Using that list for ML.NET to learn
3. Make Y-predictions for the next X-values
4. Append these predictions to the list

Result: I am always getting one single result for any following number. 
Sine is just as a varifyable function.

This is the current code:

```cs
class Program
{
    private const string FILEPATH = @"sinus.txt";
    private const float XSTART = 0f;
    private const float XEND = 20f;
    private const float XSTEP = 0.1f;
    private const float XEND_FORECAST = 30f;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GenerateSinusList();

        var pipeline = new LearningPipeline();
        pipeline.Add(new TextLoader(FILEPATH).CreateFrom<Sinus>(separator: ';'));
        pipeline.Add(new ColumnConcatenator("Features", "X"));
        pipeline.Add(new FastTreeRegressor());

        var model = pipeline.Train<Sinus, SinusForecast>();
        PredictUpcomingValues(model);

        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void PredictUpcomingValues(PredictionModel<Sinus, SinusForecast> model)
    {
        using (var sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(FILEPATH))
        {
            sw.WriteLine();
            for (double i = XEND + XSTEP; i < XEND_FORECAST; i += XSTEP)
            {
                var prediction = model.Predict(new Sinus() { X = (float)i });
                var t = string.Format("{0};{1}", i, prediction.ResultY);
                sw.WriteLine(t.Replace(',', '.')); //Quick localization fixSine
            }
            sw.Close();
        }
    }

    static void GenerateSinusList()
    {
        var sinus = GenerateSine(XSTART, XEND, XSTEP);
        var text = string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, sinus.Select(x => string.Format("{0:};{1}", x.Key, x.Value)));
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(FILEPATH, text.Replace(',', '.'));

    }

    static Dictionary<float, float> GenerateSine(float from, float to, float step)
    {
        Dictionary<float, float> result = new Dictionary<float, float>((int)((to - from) / step) + 1);

        for (double i = from; i < to; i += step)
        {
            result[(float)i] = (float)Math.Sin(i);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public class Sinus
    {
        [Column("0")]
        public float X;

        [Column("1", name: "Label")]
        public float Y;
    }

    public class SinusForecast
    {
        [ColumnName("Score")]
        public float ResultY;
    }

}
```

The result of this: Each value > 20 returns 0.5429355. The list looks like that:

- ...
- 19.4;0.523066
- 19.5;0.6055401
- 19.6;0.6819639
- 19.7;0.7515736
- 19.8;0.8136739
- 19.9;0.8676443
- 20.1;0.5429355 << first predicted
- 20.2;0.5429355
- 20.3;0.5429355
- 20.4;0.5429355
- 20.5;0.5429355
- 20.6;0.5429355
- ...

Edit: I am Using ML 0.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Decision trees are not very good at extrapolation (i.e. predicting on data that is outside the range of the training data). If you make predictions on the training data, the scores will not be constant and will actually be somewhat reasonable.

One approach to turn this into an interpolation problem is to map all the inputs to their corresponding values in one period of the sine function. If you add another features column that is mod(X, 2*Pi), you get great predictions on the test data as well.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by mapping the inputs to values and with mod(x, 2xpi)?
Sine was just for me to test something verifiable. In generall I wanted to make prediction on any curve, or even on some more streighter line.

Comment: For the case of the sine curve, you can take advantage of it being periodic (it repeats itself every 2*Pi). You can train the ML model to predict the y value based on any x within the range [0,2*Pi] by providing labeled data. You can then predict values outside that range by using the corresponding value in the original range (using the modulo operator).
For a straight line, you could use a linear model such as [SDCA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.runtime.learners.sdcaregressiontrainer?view=ml-dotnet).

Comment: For more general curves, it might be better to frame the problem as [forecasting](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/978).